# How to structure booking app for scheduled tasks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, architecture, relational-database, database-schema

I want to build a whitelabel booking app for offline services that are organized the team members schedule.

A good example would be a hair salon: There are several team members working for several hours daily and customers can book various services that take different amounts of time to complete. The customers should see which timeslots would still be available to book their services so that the schedules of the team members get filled up automatically.

My questions is: How should I model this in the database? I know this problem has been solved a million times but I could not find any information on a pattern for this.

My Suggestion:

- A table that holds all the available timeslots in 10min pieces of all the team members for the next 4 weeks
- A cron writes the newly available hours (in 4 weeks) into the table every week
- As the customers book services of the lengths of 30min, 60min etc. 3 or 6 of these 10min timeslots are assigned to the order

I hope this makes sense. I would very thankful for hints to any patterns for scheduling apps of critique on my suggestion :)

Comment: I don't see the value in the timeslots pattern, personally. If it were me, I'd just simply use a start time and end time for bookings. Combined with a roster model to handle staff working hours you should be able to achieve what you want.

Comment: @MikeCampbell the timeslots pattern may be useful if the employees have different schedules and days off. It may be simpler to store them in a database rather than to generate them dynamically.

Comment: You don't need time slots for that IMO. The working hours could be stored with start and end times too. Your application logic can then make good use of [`.cover?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Range.html#method-i-cover-3F).